# Merge value of maps in array if its has same value in keys

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an array of maps like that:

```
var data = [{'label': 'A1', 'size': 'B1', 'price' : 500,'quantity': 1},
            {'label': 'A1', 'size': 'B1', 'price' : 1000,'quantity': 1},
            {'label': 'A1', 'size': 'B2', 'price' : 500,'quantity': 1},
            {'label': 'A1', 'size': 'B2', 'price' : 500, 'quantity': 1},
            {'label': 'A2', 'size': 'B2', 'price' : 500, 'quantity': 1}];
```

I want to sum the value of price and quantity if maps have same value in label and size.
The result like this:

```
var results = [{'label': 'A1', 'size': 'B1', 'price' : 1500, 'quantity': 2},
               {'label': 'A1', 'size': 'B2', 'price' : 1000,'quantity': 2},
               {'label': 'A2', 'size': 'B2', 'price' : 500, 'quantity': 1}];
```

I'm still learning dart for a while, looked at reduce method but don't know how to implement this.

Comment: `var out = [];
data.forEach((ine) {
  var found = out.firstWhere((oute) => ine['label'] == oute['label'] && ine['size'] == oute['size'], orElse: () => null);
  if (found == null) {
    out.add(ine);
  } else {
    found['price'] += ine['price'];
    found['quantity'] += ine['quantity'];
  }
});
print(out);`

Comment: Smart answer. Really appreciate.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply iterate over the data collection using any of the following method to filter the result.

1. forEach
2. for loop
3. While
4. do-while

### Check the language tour for [more details](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#for-loops).

Here is the complete solution as per the OP's request.

```
 final List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = [
            {'label': 'A1', 'size': 'B1', 'price': 500, 'quantity': 1},
            {'label': 'A1', 'size': 'B1', 'price': 1000, 'quantity': 1},
            {'label': 'A1', 'size': 'B2', 'price': 500, 'quantity': 1},
            {'label': 'A1', 'size': 'B2', 'price': 500, 'quantity': 1},
            {'label': 'A2', 'size': 'B2', 'price': 500, 'quantity': 1}
          ];
          var tempMap = {};
          var result = [];
          data.forEach((value) {
            var prevValue = tempMap[value['label'] + "_" + value['size']];
            if (prevValue != null) {
              var price = value['price'] + prevValue['price'];
              var quantity = value['quantity'] + prevValue['quantity'];
              prevValue.update(
                'price',
                (existingValue) => price,
                ifAbsent: () => price,
              );
              prevValue.update(
                'quantity',
                (existingValue) => quantity,
                ifAbsent: () => quantity,
              );
              tempMap.update(
                value['label'] + "_" + value['size'],
                (existingValue) => prevValue,
                ifAbsent: () => prevValue,
              );
            } else {
              tempMap.putIfAbsent(
                  value['label'] + "_" + value['size'], () => value);
            }
          });

          tempMap.forEach((key, value) {
            result.add(value);
          });


          print("$result");
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that with just simple iterate. Can you show me the way? Thank you.

Comment: @Michael Updated the answer with complete solution