# Flutter merge array which have same name

Tags: flutter, dart

I have array like this

```
[{
“providerName”: “ABC”,
“data1”: “asd”
“data2: “asd”
},
{
“providerName”: “ABC”,
“data1”: “asd”
“data2: “asd”
},
{
“providerName”: “DEF”,
“data1”: “dsa”
“data2: “dosa”
},
{
“providerName”: “GHI”,
“data1”: “ghg”
“data2: “hg”
}]
```

I want to merge the array in which the provider name is the same and save other data in one array.

So I am expecting output like this

```
[{
“providerName”: “ABC”, “dataMerge”: [{“data1”: “asd”,“data2: “asd”}, {“data1”: “asd”, “data2: “asd”}},
{
“providerName”: “DEF”, “dataMerge”: [{“data1”: “dsa”, “data2: “dosa”}
},
{
“providerName”: “GHI”, “dataMerge”: [{“data1”: “ghg”, “data2: “hg”},
}]
```

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60108481/merge-value-of-maps-in-array-if-its-has-same-value-in-keys?rq=1

Comment: check [groupListsBy](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/groupListsBy.html) or [groupBy](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/groupBy.html)